# как получить метку optgroup имея текущий option в select2?

Tags: jquery, select2

есть код, построеный плагином select2.

```
<optgroup label="Днепропетровская">
  <option value="10331">Андреевка</option>
  <option value="10026">Авиаторское</option>   <!-------
  <option value="10541">Аполлоновка</option>
  <option value="10545">Апостолово</option>
  <option value="10626">Бабайковка</option>
  <option value="11652">Богатое</option>
  <option value="10804">Баловка</option>
....
```

Вот этой шляпой `$("#cities_"+provider_id).select2("data")[0]` я получаю выбранный элемент в виде массива

```
{selected: true, disabled: false, text: "Авиаторское", id: "10026", title: "", …}
```

Мне надо получить `label` от `optgroup` выбранного `option`, а именно "Днепропетровская". Пробовал через closest('optgroup'), parent(), parents('optgroup'), но чё-то не получается, хотя казалось бы ничего сложного.

прикрепляю вывод консоли для ясности в получаемых данных
[image: вывод консоли]

Comment: А что возвращает "шляпа"? jQuery-объект или HTMLElement?

Comment: Даже из документации не понятно select2('data') "will return a JavaScript array of objects" - что за массив объектов

Comment: Допёр. Пробуйте так: $( один_элемент_из_шляпы.element ).closest('optgroup').attr('label')

Comment: в вопрос я добавил вывод консоли, где видны типы получаемых данных.

Comment: ну в данном случае вы предлагаете $("#cities_"+provider_id).select2("data").closest('optgroup').attr('label') и оно не работает почему-то, я уже пробовал

Comment: Нет. Я предложил так: var elem = $( $("#cities_"+provider_id).select2("data")[0].element ), и уже у него вызывать closest.

Comment: Работает!! $($("#cities_"+provider_id).select2("data")[0].element).closest('optgroup').attr('label')  Спасибо! А откуда вы взяли ".element" ?

Comment: Просто в консоли у себя попробовал вывести "шляпу" и увидел что там какой-то массив итемов. У каждого итема есть свойство элемент, вы сами это можете увидеть, если в консоли развернёте объект из "шляпы". Это стандартная страгетия всех подобных шляп.

Comment: очень признателен, снимаю шляпу)